# how to remove a fee line from a woocommerce order using REST API?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to remove a fee line from an order using the woocommerce REST API. I tried passing the fee_lines as an empty array, or with the name and total of the fee line set to null or zero and none of it worked. I am using the V3 Woocommerce API. Thanks

I tried to delete the fee line by:

- removing it from the fee_lines array
- passing the whole fee_lines array as an empty array
- sending the id of the fee line on (no name or total)
- setting the fee line's name and total as null or zero

Comment: this question also applies to the shipping_lines as well

Comment: show the code that so we can help, per documentation, you can try something like this, 
 substr_replace($string ,"", -1);  replaces the last char in a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the woocommerce source code and I found that there is not direct way to do that for fee lines. based on what I found , the only way to remove a fee line or shipping line is to set one of the following attributes as null
method_id, product_id, title, code

For shipping lines, we have the method_id attribute, so by setting it as null I solved the problem

For fee lines, none of the indicated attributes belongs to the fee lines based on the documentation. so added them manually to my source code and set them to null. that way it worked and I did not have to edit the woocommerce source code

below is the php code

```
$payload['fee_lines'][$k]['method_id'] = NULL;  
$payload['fee_lines'][$k]['product_id'] = NULL; 
$payload['fee_lines'][$k]['title'] = NULL;  
$payload['fee_lines'][$k]['code'] = NULL;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What endpoint are you using?

You should be using the [`Update an Order`](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#update-an-order) endpoint. Also make sure you are using a `PUT` request in this case as it shows in the docs. From there you can set `fee_lines` to an empty array.